# Spread children in jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the jsx equivalent of

```
React.createElement('dl', {}, ...errorTermDescriptions(errors))
```

---

I've tried

```
<dl>
  {errorTermDescriptions(errors)}
</dl>
```

which gives me a key error (I know, I know, but in this case I really don't want to use keys). This is because it is equivalent to

```
React.createElement('dl', {}, errorTermDescriptions(errors))
```

(no spread). Which is not what I want

```
<dl>
  {...errorTermDescriptions(errors)}
</dl>
```

in the meantime webpack freaks out over

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (377:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|         __self: _this
|       },
|       {...errorTermDescriptions(errors)}
|     )
|   );
```

This is something that's very simple in javascript, what is the jsx equivalent?

Its fine if it's not possible, I just want an authoritative answer.

Comment: what does `errorTermDescriptions(errors)` return?

Comment: @Ted its a generator function. That returns an iterable. Iterables are the only thing that can be spread. To be clear I have the non-jsx-version working perfectly fine now. I'm not asking for a discussion on keys, I'm asking for the jsx equivalent of the js version

Comment: Researching further, the plot thickens, seems like this is something that babel [supports fine](https://babeljs.io/en/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=DwEwNgfAUABDDeA6ZBTATmg9mgKugtgCIoDOAxmgJYAOALpZgHYkAU6WaJAlAL5TAB6cBCA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact&prettier=true&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=)

Comment: it's `{[...errorTermDescriptions(errors)]}`. for some reason React JSX only accepts arrays and component objects so you HAVE to spread it to an array first, unfortunately.